# How can I declare a function definition type which is a non-arrow function?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface called `Autocomplete` where I want to include a method with the following declaration:

```
export interface Autocomplete {
    filterOptions: (name: string) => any[];
}
```

When I implement my interface it gives me this implementation as an arrow function:

```
 filterOptions: (name: string) => any[];
```

I need a normal function declaration so at the end I would get:

```
filterOptions(name:string) {
   return any[];
}
```

How do I need to define my method in the interface so I will get

```
filterOptions(name:string) {
   return any[];
}
```

instead of an arrow function

```
filterOptions: (name: string) => any[];
```

Comment: That _is_ a normal function declaration. TypeScript doesn't distinguish them in types, it's just a callable thing. You can write the actual implementation either way. It seems like by _"When I implement my interface..."_ you really mean when something generates it for you - what?

Comment: *"When I implement my interface it gives me..."* **What** gives you that? Some editor or IDE? You could try adding `this: Autocomplete` as the first "parameter" in the function definition, but if the editor/IDE doesn't realize from that that it should be a method definition rather than an arrow function (VS Code doesn't, for instance), you just have to fix it after the IDE's done the basic scaffolding for you.

Comment: @johnsharpe I edited my question. i need normal function when i implement my interface

Comment: Editor - VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Comment: Use arrow functions... When I see a normal function in javascript I assume it's a 6 year old code base.

Comment: @Matriarx - If the OP is writing a class with `implements Autocomplete`, they're going to want methods. There's nothing old-fashioned about methods rather than arrow functions. Arrow functions are an *additional* tool, not a replacement for traditional functions or methods.

Comment: @ViswanathaSwamy - Edits adding ALL CAPS aren't useful, and the OP's "I have an" was absolutely fine and correct, no need to change it to "I am having." Also, the word "I" is always in upper case. In your edit, you changed the OP's "I" to "i" which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export interface Autocomplete {
  filterOptions(name: string): any[];
}

class Test implements Autocomplete {
    // VSCode implementation
    filterOptions(name: string): any[] {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that when you write

```typescript
class Something implements Autocomplete {
}
```

and then you use the VS Code "Quick fix" called "Implement interface 'Autocomplete'", you get this:

```typescript
class Something implements Autocomplete {
    filterOptions: (name: string) => any[];
}
```

then unfortunately I don't think you can change the interface definition to make VS Code write it as a method instead (but keep reading).

Two options for you (the first isn't very satisfying, but...):

### 1. Live with it and edit after

Just to get it out of the way, one option is to live with it and edit the resulting code while doing the implementation. It's just a matter of removing the `:`  after the method name, changing the  `=>` to `:`, and replacing the `;` with `{}` (and adding the implementation:

```typescript
class Something implements Autocomplete {
    filterOptions(name: string): any[] {
        // ...implementation...
    }
}
```

I had hoped that providing a hint to VS Code by using `this: Autocomplete` as the first parameter might help:

```typescript
// DOESN'T HELP (I'd just hoped it would)
export interface Autocomplete {
    filterOptions: (this: Autocomplete, name: string) => any[];
}
```

but sadly it doesn't.

### 2. Abstract Class

You could make the interface an abstract class instead:

```typescript
export abstract class Autocomplete {
    abstract filterOptions(name: string): any[];
}
```

Then when you use the Quick Fix "Implement inherited abstract class" you get:

```typescript
class Something extends Autocomplete {
    filterOptions(name: string): any[] {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

But you may not want to use an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can cast but it looks very weird:

```js
const filterOptions = (function(name) {
   return any[];
} as Autocomplete);
```